# float: left <li>: items disappear at overflow

Tags: css, layout, css-float

## Context

If you `float: left` list items in an un-ordered list and they horizontally overflow the page, they disappear one at a time, instead of showing half a list item for example.

It's hard to explain in English, so here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfumfckg/2/):

```
ul { height: 38px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap }
ul li { list-style-type: none; padding: 10px; border-right: 1px solid black; display: inline }
```

Try horizontally resizing the result window, and you'll see how list items completely disappear as soon as they overflow.

This of course doesn't happen when [using `display:inline` instead](https://jsfiddle.net/o8wcux3L/1/), but unfortunately it's incredibly difficult to style. Here's a picture from the actual website:

`float: left`: Last tab not visible at all:
[image]
`displat: inline`: Horrible things happen:
[image]

`display: inline-block` also breaks the style, so I don't prefer at unless it's my only option.

## The Question

Could you possibly avoid this clipping problem while still using `float: left`?

Comment: That's because you are using `overflow:hidden`... so its hiding the overflow like you told it to.

Comment: What behavior do you expect when viewport is has smaller resolution, what do you expect from the list items, to wrap?

Comment: If you want to keep floating the items, then you will have to give the UL a fixed width, so that all items will fit next to each other (and then apply the overflow cutoff to an additional container element.) I don't know what exact difficulties you're having with inline-block, but if this is about the white space between elements, please do proper research, that's a known and easily fixable issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a container, and apply overflow to it. Check this out. Does this solves your problem?

```css
.container {overflow: hidden}
ul { height:38px; padding:0; white-space: nowrap; overflow:auto}
ul li { list-style-type: none; padding:10px; border-right:1px solid black; display:inline }
```

```html
<div class="container"><ul>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>ipsum</li>
<li>dolor</li>
<li>sit amit</li>
<li>consectetur</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>ipsum</li>
<li>dolor</li>
<li>sit amit</li>
<li>consectetur</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>ipsum</li>
<li>dolor</li>
<li>sit amit</li>
<li>consectetur</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>ipsum</li>
<li>dolor</li>
<li>sit amit</li>
<li>consectetur</li>
</ul></div>
```